# Console o/p data to log file is not formatted (Python script)

Tags: python

I have a python script using which I call a command that lauches a software (which runs a simulation) and then after completion the simu software is closed. The simulation s/w has a console window on which some o/p is displayed.

If I would have launched this simu manually using a shell without then I can also see the o/p of this simu s/w console window in the shell.

My primary target is to write this console window o/p to a log file.

Hence I did the following and it is working.

```
import commands
logging.basicConfig(...)
.
.
.    
simu_cmd = "my_cmd"
logging.info(commands.getstatusoutput(simu_cmd))
.
.
```

Now when I open my log file after the python script completes execution, then I see the complete expected o/p written out in the log file.

But there is NO FORMATTING of the data. It is just like a big string printed one after the other. There are spaces in between words, but are problems with 'new lines'. I can even see '\n' and '\r' characters in my log files.

Can anyone please suggest how to I write the formatted output to the log file or improve on the code I have written?

Note- May be I am using an old process to write out to a log file, but I want to keep it stupid and simple. In some thread here some people have mentioned the useage of subprocess(), but it looked complicated to me. I will always be using a Linux m/c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are logging the result of `commands.getstatusoutput()` which is not just the output of the command but a *tuple* with two elements — the status value and the output of the command.  If you log that tuple you will get the string representation of that tuple and strings in tuples are converted with the `repr()` function into the string representation within the tuple.

Here is an example of the difference:

```
In [27]: result = (0, 'one\ntwo')

In [28]: print result
(0, 'one\ntwo')

In [29]: print result[1]
one
two
```

Comment: Thanks BlackJack for the explanation! Works perfect. I just changed to logging.info(commands.getstatusoutput(simu_cmd)[1]) and could get a nice formatted output in the log file.